# Can deer be at the zoo if there are deer at the zoo, and some deer have antlers?

Tags: logic

> - Some deer have antlers.
> - There are deer at the zoo.

Which is **the** conclusion based on the above statements?

1. Deer can be at the zoo.
2. All deer with antlers are to be found at the zoo.
3. Antlers of a deer are pretty.
4. At the zoo, some deer can have antlers.
5. The zoo is the only place where deer live.
6. Deer at the zoo have antlers.

Apparently the answer is #4. It's a 'can', so ok, I guess? But in that case, why not #1? I guess #1 is wrong if 'can' is used [in the sense of permission](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1tv925/tomtimagequote_a_response_to_the_whole_its_may_i/cebrysr/).

ETA:

- I think #4 is wrong because of the possibility that the deer with antlers happen to not be found at the zoo. The mere possibility is sufficient to conclude that it does not follow that the zoo deer have antler potential.
- For #1 however, no non-contradictory condition can ever make it false. Hence, it is right.

Comment: Maybe here they mean "can" as possible but strictly not necessary? As in, some of the deer at the zoo *can* have antlers, but they don't necessarily. Saying deer *can* be at the zoo, in this sense, isn't correct, since the deer **are** at the zoo, it is strictly necessary based on the second of the given statements.

Comment: This is why I hate problems like this. It is usually linguistics, rather than logic, that actually gives the issues.

Comment: It would help if you give context to the question. Presumably you did not come up with it yourself.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 Made a mistake for #2! Edited. Thanks for the insight on #1.

Comment: @Alexander: If that's the reason, then this is a really terrible play on semantics and ambiguity.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I completely agree, which is why I left it as a comment; I'm more trying to fit the question to the answer than vice-versa.

Comment: What I can think of is that #1 is just based on the second statement, while #4 combines both statements. However, if that is the idea, the question is poorly stated.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93: If it is false that deer *can* be at the zoo, doesn't that mean deer *can't* be at the zoo?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, but I would emphasise it as "deer can **not** be in the zoo", as in, it is possible that they are not in the zoo, but not strictly impossible for them to be there.

Comment: **If** we avoid the use of *modal* logic, the only plausible sense of "can": is "zero or more". Thus: "Deer can be at the zoo" must be read as: "Either there are some deer at the zoo or none at all", which is quite useless.

Comment: **If** we remove "can", clearly  "Deer can be at the zoo" is simply: "There are deer at the zoo", that is the 2nd premise.

Comment: But if we remove "can", 4 does not follows: from "Some deer have antlers" (that is "There are deer that are antlers") and "There are deer at the zoo" we cannot conclude with: "At the zoo, some deer [can] have antlers" (that is: "There are deer at the zoo that are antlers").

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think I just figured it out. It's possible that the deer who have antlers are the ones not in the zoo. The possibility alone is sufficient to say that it doesn't follow that the deer at the zoo can have antlers! I think? My thought is that if you had any non-contradictory condition, #1 will always be true. However, the same does not apply to #4. Therefore, #4 is not right.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, let's look at the options:

1. "Deer can be at the zoo" - I would vote for this because if there are deer at the zoo, then deer CAN be at the zoo.
2. All deer with antlers can be found at the zoo: There is no proof that the deers with antlers and the deer who are at the zoo would overlap in any way. So: this is not true.
3. Antlers of a deer are pretty: A subjective statement, so no.
4. At the zoo, some deer can have antlers: As in the second statement, there is no proof of overlapping. But there can be some overlapping - we don't know.
5. The zoo is the only place where deer live: It was only said that there are some deer at the zoo, so we cannot say that all of them would be there.
6. Deer at the zoo have antlers: again the same logic as in the second and fourth point.

Therefore, only the first point is in any way logical.

Comment: But the only way to support it is to use *modal logic* (and - frankly speaking - it does not seem to me that modal logic must be used at that elementary level): from $\exists x Px$ to $\diamond \exists x Px$ (it there are deer at the zoo, then it is possible that there are deer at the zoo).

Comment: @BCLC: #1 is the only one that follows from the premises. Because only some deer are at the zoo, and only some deer have antlers, the premises do not tell us if deer at the zoo can have antlers.  By analogy: some people do whatever they want, and some people are in jail - these do not imply that some people in jail can do whatever they want. Some people are dead, and some are alive, but it does not follow that some dead people can be alive.

Comment: @CarlMummert 'Some deer have antlers $\to$ some deer can have antlers $\to$ some deer at the zoo can have antlers.' --> What's wrong with this? Edit: Oh wait, I think I just figured it out. It's possible that the deer who have antlers are the ones not in the zoo. Therefore, it doesn't follow that the deer at the zoo can have antlers! I think?

Comment: @CarlMummert For #4, I'm thinking some humans are male. Soooo 'some humans in the US are male' does not necessarily follow because all the male humans could be outside the US. But 'some humans in the US *can* be male' is...hmmm...actually also false for the same reason?

Comment: @BCLC: exactly like you said, maybe the deer at the zoo can't have antlers even though other deer can.   it's not that the statement "deer at the zoo can have antlers" has to be false - that statement can't be deduced just from the assumptions that were given

Comment: @CarlMummert right thanks though arguably well that's what false means right? :P